# Converting a python list into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

So I'm trying to form a javascript array of dates that I can feed as input to a jquery datepicker addon.  My Django view is:

```
def autofill_featured(request):
    show_id = request.GET.get('show_id')
    show = Show.objects.get(id=show_id)
    data = [] 
    for listing in show.listings.all():
        string = str(listing.date.month) + '/' + str(listing.date.day) + '/' + str(listing.date.year)
        data.append(string)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

My javascript is currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var preselect = function () {
        var results = $.ajax({
            url: "/autofill_featured",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {show_id: $("#id_show_id").val()}
        });
        return results;
    };
    $("#picker").multiDatesPicker({
        addDates: preselect()
    });
```

If I manually specify

```
addDates: ['6/29/2011', '6/30/2011']
```

then it works, but trying to pass it the results of preselect and I get an error: "o_dates[0].getTime is not a function".  According to the multiDatesPicker docs I can supply either an array of strings in the date format I used above, or an array of javascript date objects.  How can I take the json that is returned by my Django view and turn it into a js array?

The docs for the jquery addon I'm trying to use are here, if it helps: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

I'm very new to JS and don't really know what's going wrong. Any ideas?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of code is wrong:

```
var preselect = function () {
    var results = $.ajax({
        url: "/autofill_featured",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {show_id: $("#id_show_id").val()}
    });
    return results;
};
```

`$.ajax` function does return `jqXHR` object, not ajax call result. What You need is to add success callback (Browser JS is all about callbacks) to Your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    /* ... */
    success: function (data) {
        /* Set date pickers date 
           I am  not sure about multiDatePicker API */
    }
});
```

But I think it is wrong approach to make additional request just to prefill some date picker. Maybe, You can pass dates list when You are actually generating Your view with date picker?